# Splitting lines in a file using bash and writing back to file does nothing

Tags: bash, file-io, while-loop

I'm trying to loop through each line in a file, separate by comma and do something with it.  Importantly I want the change to be written to the same file.  This code does not give errors but hangs and does nothing.  Any suggestions or better solutions?

```
file='file.txt'
while IFS=',' read -ra f1 f2
do
  echo "field # 1 : $f1 ==> field #2 : $f2" 
done >> $file
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you command is wrong simply. You are not not even reading the file. To read a file you need `< file` after done.

```
file='file.txt'
while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2
do
  echo "field # 1 : $f1 ==> field #2 : $f2" 
done < "$file" > output
```

Comment: Yes tried that but it outputs it to screen and does not change file.txt

Comment: See updated code where it redirects output to `output` file. Later you can do `mv output file.txt`

Comment: Yes OK, so its not possible to overwrite file.txt but I have to mv the temp output file to file.txt.  Also, I seem to get ^M at the end of each line in output, have any idea why?

Comment: That is because your input file already has `\r` at end of line. You can use `dos2unix` command to remove them.